# How to format bytes from strings to hex values

Tags: python, encoding, string-formatting, big5

I am reading in a binary file with big5 encoded characters. When I read a double byte sequence, they would appear as a list of bytes e.g.

```
>>> bytes = ['0xa6', '0x7b']
```

If I modify these string bytes:

```
>>> big5_str = ''
>>> for hexVal in bytes:
>>>     newHexVal = '\\' + hexVal[1:]
>>>     big5_str += newHexVal
```

so they appear as:

```
>>> print big5_str
>>> '\xa6\x7b'
```

but big5_str actually has the escape '\' still in the string:

```
>>> big5_str
>>> '\\xa6\\x7b'
```

and if i decode using big5, I only get the same string back (due to the double-backslash):

```
>>> print byte_string.decode('big5')
>>> '\xa6\x7b'
```

If I explicitly code the the byte sequence as the hex values:

```
>>> bytes2 = '\xa6\x7b'
>>> print bytes2.decode('big5')
>>> 州
```

My question is, how can I read these bytes, format them in '\x**' format them so that they are recognized as bytes, not strings, using a non-escaped backslash?

Comment: You're reading them incorrectly. Why are they read in as '0xa6' (4 bytes) instead of '\xa6' which represents a single byte? Your bytes list should be `['\xa6', '\x7b']`. Check your read function, why is it returning a list of 4-byte strings?

Comment: You can also convert your incorrect byte representation to a correct one by using `map( lambda x: chr( int( x, 16 ) ), bytes )`. Join that with `''` and decode. Full code would be `''.join( map( lambda x: chr( int( x, 16 ) ), bytes ) ).decode( 'big5' )`. But again, check your read function, you're doing a lot of unnecessary work because of it.

Comment: You were right, I read in the file with hex values (as I needed those to process another part of the file). I ended up returning the list of single bytes and convert to hex where needed. Thanks!